# いやこうしている in this statement

Tags: grammar

Speaker asked how he was doing after waking up from his injuries.

> Q「それよりも大丈夫？　痛むところとかない？」
>
> speaker「いや……ありまくりだ。痛くないところがない」
>
> speaker **指一本、いやこうしているだけでも、断続的に節々が痛む。**
>
> speaker 寝たきりだった体を起こした時のような鈍い痛みが全身に走っていて、それは彼女と森で出会った頃よりも強く感じられた。

my finger, ugh though it's like this (everywhere hurts?), hurts intermittently

How do i interpret いやこうしている here?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could understand the sentence like this...

> 指一本（動かしただけで…）、いや、こうしているだけでも、断続的に節々が痛む。

By 指一本, he tries to say something like 指一本動かしただけで、～～, but corrects himself by saying いや、"no", こうしているだけでも、～～.

"(By moving just) a finger... no, even when I'm staying (still) like this, my joints hurt intermittently."